# Accessing Google Account Id /username via Android

Tags: android, google-account

How do you access the user's Google Account Id / username in code?  I am building an application that will call a web service to store data and I want to identify the identity of the person submitting the data.

Comment: Get Google Account Username and Email 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31538053/4395114

Comment: There is also a library for account management in android [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227274/how-to-add-programmatically-a-custom-account-in-android/39686087#39686087).

Answer (score 47):

I've ran into the same issue and these two links solved for me:

The first one is this one: [How do I retrieve the logged in Google account on android phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038333/how-do-i-retrieve-the-logged-in-google-account-on-android-phones)

Which presents the code for retrieving the accounts associated with the phone. Basically you will need something like this:

```
AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
```

And to add the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
```

Additionally, if you are using the Emulator the following link will help you to set it up with an account : [Android Emulator - Trouble creating user accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260868/android-emulator-trouble-creating-user-accounts)

Basically, it says that you must create an android device based on a API Level and not the SDK Version (like is usually done).

Comment: how can I get the account avatar ? Thank you so much`

Comment: @Urchin this is a little bit out of the scope of this question, but I believe this other one could help ya. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905066/get-user-name-avatar-from-google-account

Comment: A bit late but this may help someone if you trying to get account's avatar (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128700/getting-google-profile-picture-url-with-user-id)

Comment: There is also a library for account management in android [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227274/how-to-add-programmatically-a-custom-account-in-android/39686087#39686087).

Answer (score 10):

This Method to get Google Username:

```
 public String getUsername() {
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    List<String> possibleEmails = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (Account account : accounts) {
        // TODO: Check possibleEmail against an email regex or treat
        // account.name as an email address only for certain account.type
        // values.
        possibleEmails.add(account.name);
    }

    if (!possibleEmails.isEmpty() && possibleEmails.get(0) != null) {
        String email = possibleEmails.get(0);
        String[] parts = email.split("@");
        if (parts.length > 0 && parts[0] != null)
            return parts[0];
        else
            return null;
    } else
        return null;
}
```

simple this method call ....

And Get Google User in Gmail id::

```
 accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
    Log.e("", "Size: " + accounts.length);
    for (Account account : accounts) {

        String possibleEmail = account.name;
        String type = account.type;

        if (type.equals("com.google")) {
            strGmail = possibleEmail;

            Log.e("", "Emails: " + strGmail);
            break;
        }
    }
```

After add permission in manifest;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: Why interenet and access network state permissions are required?

Answer (score 6):

> Retrieve profile information for a signed-in user
>    Use the GoogleSignInResult.getSignInAccount method to request profile information for the currently signed in user.
>   You can call the getSignInAccount method after the sign-in intent succeeds.

```
GoogleSignInResult result = 
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
String personId = acct.getId();
Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
  Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
  String userid=currentPerson.getId(); //BY THIS CODE YOU CAN GET CURRENT LOGIN USER ID
}
```

Comment: What lib are you using, I get `Plus` _Cannot resolve symbol_ ?

Comment: This is based on using the Google+ API which is probably too exotic for most developers

Answer (score 2):

Used these lines:

```
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
```

the length of array accounts is always 0.

Comment: Please use android device below Android 6.0 - 6.… (API levels 23-…) , because higher version device required run-time permissions and it will always return length 0.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample from google, which lists the existing google accounts and generates an access token upon selection , you can send that access token to server to retrieve the related details from it to identify the user.

You can also get the email id from access token , for that you need to modify the SCOPE

Please go through [My Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15300129/877994)

Answer (score -4):

```
String name = android.os.Build.USER;

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
    nameEdit.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried this and it returned me "dpi". Clearly not the user's name.