# Retrieve user's name from IMEI number- Android

Tags: android

I need to find a user's name from the IMEI number of that particular phone. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I need to find a user's name from the IMEI number of that particular phone. Is it possible to do that?
```

**NO**, that´s not possible!, there´s no relation between this two values.

You can get google username on an Android Device but you don´t need the IMEI.

More info:
**[How can I get the google username on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727029/how-can-i-get-the-google-username-on-android)**

Comment: Elenasys-: Fine thanks. So can you please explain how to get the google username by android? :)