# Reasonable default user name?

Tags: android

I'm adding multiuser support to my app and want to provide a reasonable default name for the 1st user.

I can invent something like 'Default User' or 'User 1' or 'Me' or something.

However, can I get something from any data stored in the phone, something which will reasonably identify the user and which the user would, possibly, not, immediately at least, to change?

Comment: maybe user defined device name can be handy `Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "lock_screen_owner_info");`

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727029/how-can-i-get-the-google-username-on-android