# obtaining the user name of any user

Tags: android, multi-user, limited-user

I am currently using the following code to obtain the current user name:

```
        String username;
        {
            Cursor c = ctx.getContentResolver().query(Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{Profile.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
            if (c.getCount() > 0)
            {
                c.moveToFirst();
                username = c.getString(0);
            }
```

On my test device (Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro), with the correct permissions, this works well for the "owner" user, as well as other non-restricted users. However, things seem to fall apart for limited user profiles:

- The code always returns zero cursor rows. I had hoped that enabling access to the Contacts app would allow it to work, but that has no effect.
- At any rate, unlike non-limited profiles, the profile of the limited user account does not seem to be connected to the name displayed on the lock screen, so even if I could get this code to work I'm not sure how useful it would be.

Please forgive the multi-part question, but:

- Is this a peculiarity of the Samsung tablet, or is this behavior consistent across devices?
- Is there any way to read the profile of a limited user?
- Is there a better way to obtain the current user name?

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: This will help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727029/how-can-i-get-the-google-username-on-android

Comment: No, I am not looking for an email address.

Comment: have you add permission to read profile data?

Comment: Yes, as I stated, and it works fine for non-restricted user profiles

Comment: what you mean non-restricted ? you can get only owner profile detail. Other are guest user

Comment: When adding a new user, the options are "User" and "Restricted profile". This code works on all regular users, not just the owner. But I'd like to be able to obtain a user name for restricted profiles as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to search about it & can say it's not possible to get details of **"Restricted Profile (User)".**

In background when you try to read details for "Restricted Profile user" they are trying to change in database and throw `SQLiteexception : delete then re-write existing database throws SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException on getWritableDatabase`. due to this exception I don't think there is chance to read user name.

Without use your above code you can get directly call `getUsername()` of [UserManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#getUserName()) class.[API Level 17]

Comment: Unfortunately, for reasons unknown and probably unknowable, `getUserName()` requires `MANAGE_USERS` permission, which is impossible to get for SDK apps.

Comment: Yes, if we have chunk of code then why we should go for more api level. Let me know if you get any luck on it.

Comment: OK, this is strange. I said earlier that "the profile of the limited user account does not seem to be connected to the name displayed on the lock screen", and that was true then. However, my lock screen has now started displaying the name from the profile, and my code is now working to get the user name! I guess there's some strange lag between creating a profile for a limited user and having that profile work? I'm definitely leaving this question open to see if anyone has anything to add, particularly about other device models.

Comment: it's relay strange. good that now it's working. have you change to add anything? then pls share.

Comment: I changed the name in the limited user's profile again. My code kept reading the old name for a long time. Finally it is seeing the update. There's something really weird about how this all works (or doesn't work) within a limited account.

Comment: My code hasn't changed. It's just been me playing with the tablet.