# AccountManager return empty accounts

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have an app which is implementing my own Authenticator as described in [this](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) article. And it works fine as intended. Now I need to get google account from AccountManager and I am doing it this way:

```
 Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");
```

The problem is that it return an empty array. But when I am using this snippet in my test app without all Authenticator stuff it works like a charm. I can't see where is an actual difference between these cases. Has anybody faced with this issue?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. Are you saying that line of code works when you don't have your own Authenticator? Or are you saying that your own Authenticator works for getting your accounts, but you can never get Google accounts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727029/how-can-i-get-the-google-username-on-android

Comment: @DanielLew the second one. If I query all accounts I will get only the one from my app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is that you lack the [`GET_ACCOUNTS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS) permission. You can get your own app's accounts without it but access to other accounts requires permission.

It's a bit more complex than simply requesting `GET_ACCOUNTS` in the manifest these days because of [runtime permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Now you have to request them dynamically, and the message shown to users for `GET_ACCOUNTS` is pretty cryptic (it asks for access to contacts, since it's part of the contacts permission group).

You may want to look into using [`AccountPicker`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker) (from Google Play Services), which requires no permissions. It presents a dialog to the user with the requested accounts (and gives an option to add a new account, too).

Comment: You are right!  The problem was in runtime permission. I was confused because in me test app permission was granted. As soon as it was revoked behaviour of both apps became the same. Many thanks! And btw thank you for your articles about Rx and styling =)