# How can one get a mobile device users full name?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile

I'm using Cordova and the band would be required for display purposes. I could have the user input it, but if I can snag it programmatically that'd be preferred.

Comment: The device object holds some of the required information such as name,uuid, platform,version, model . you could use it as such . device.name
device.cordova
device.platform
device.uuid
device.version
device.model

Comment: @IamKarim1992 I need the users full name "Bob Jones" for example. If it's not possible programmatically I'll settle for user input.

Comment: So, where in the device could u find that ?

Comment: @IamKarim1992 that's what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

Ok , There are couple of Android implementation to accomplish that , U have to wrap that as a plugin which returns the result after `onDeviceReady`. The Android Implementations are

1.You can try to access their information stored in a Google account, requiring the GET_ACCOUNTS permission

2.There is also a READ_PROFILE permission and which can be done by accesing ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds` , but it gives only a possibility of finding user info. U have to check Android Version as well .

So Basically all the Android Native code would be wrapped as Cordova Plugin which returns u a possible dataset of values.

See These Links as well.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.html

https://gist.github.com/imminent/4061516

This is Android Implementation but it could me made as a plugin .

How to make a cordova plugin :- 
http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-creating-a-cordova-phonegap-plugin-for-android-app/

Some StackOverflow links

[How can I get the google username on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727029/how-can-i-get-the-google-username-on-android)

I have done something similar with my project , it gets user details and user specific role from a  private AppStore and renders Different UI and Screens Based on Roles.

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS you'll have to create a plugin that executes this code

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice]name]
```