# How do I register my Google Account in the android emulator running 2.2 api level 8?

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Emulator - Trouble creating user accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260868/android-emulator-trouble-creating-user-accounts)

I'm trying to register a Google Account with the Android emulator running 2.2 API level 8. Forums suggest that you can do this by going to Settings -> Accounts, however for me I only have the option to add a "corporate" account, i.e. an Exchange account, not a Google Account.

I wish to add this Google Account to test c2dm from the emulator.

Does anyone know how to associate a Google account with the emulator in this build?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Turns out I was using the image "Android 2.2" instead of "Google APIS (Google Inc)". Using the Android SDK and AVD Manager, create a new virtual machine with the correct image.

Comment: great! Still can't install apps from the Play Store onto a emulated device though :-/