# Android GCM registration failed. Why?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I was trying to use GCM to have push-notification in my app. I called `GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID)`, but I got an error.

My manifest file:

```
   <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="com.salamworld"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
```

And here's the error:

> DEBUG/GCMBaseIntentService(423): Registration error: ACCOUNT_MISSING

My GCMIntentService class:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService{

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.d("@R@", registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exception comes when you don't have a Google Account in your device,

> [ACCOUNT_MISSING](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html) - There is no Google account on the phone. The Android
>   application should ask the user to open the account manager and add a
>   Google account. Fix on the device side.

Comment: Actually, I'm running on the emulator. What should I do

Comment: You should better try in device, as your Emulator is by default not configured to have an google account. [You can also check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3796495/726863)

Comment: @servus-libertatem You can add a Google account in the emulator. Make sure you have created an emulator with Google APIs (API level whatever).

Comment: but without google account how can be app downloaded from play store