# Target Account ContactManger Sample?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I've imported ContactManager Sample and run successfully. In the add form to add a new contact, I found a field named "Target Account".

Can you explain to me :

- What is a target account ?
- What is it used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `Target Account` is account you had in device. They represent for each user of device. As you know every device has at least one gmail account to start. When you run this sample in real device that target account spinner will display all account you have. 
[image]
If you want create account in emulator following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3260868/1050058)

Comment: Thanks in advance Yul. If i don't have a target account, what happen?

Comment: I think contact cannot be added. And this case is not possible because you must setup an account in order to start use real device. Your phone simple not start without an account. For chatty question you can come to this [room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people). I often hangout there.

Comment: Now, I had 3 reputation, so i can't come there. You come from VietNam Yul? Give me some info about you: email, yahoo, etc...

Comment: Please help me resolve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188384/how-to-edit-contact-from-context-menu