# Can't create/add account @emulated android device

Tags: android, synchronization, account, device-emulation

I never used android before but I'm really interested to try so I installed eclipse and sdk so far. I managed to create a virtual device using jelly bean and it seems to work fine. I can browse the internet etc.

Now I wanted to install a few apps on the emulator from google playstore but I need to connect or synch my device. I found lots of posts how to do this. Apparently I just have to go to the settings of the emulated device and add my account.

The problem is, I just can't add an account. Every time I click on "add account" nothing happens, so I can't add anything at all. Most of the issues concerning this are about some error messages etc. but I don't even get that far.

There is supposed to be also something like accounts & sync @ "personal" - this is not displayed on the emulated device. There's only location services, security, language & input, backup & reset.

maybe someone can explain me what I did wrong?

Comment: What image are you installing on the emulator? There are two, an Android api and a Google api.

Comment: [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3260868/1050058). You should create emulator from Google API not Android API.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have most likely installed the Android 4.1.2 image on the emulator. You will want to try the Google APIs (Google Inc) - API Level 16 which will give you access to adding accounts.

Comment: This worked! Didn't know I need to use Google APIs to create the account. Thx a lot!