# ADD ACCOUNT is not working in my Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

In my android Emulator , i am not able to config the Gmail Account details using Add account.
If i clicks the button, there is no response from the Emulator.

I also tried accessing the Adding account feature using Intent (using StartActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT)) ). Even that is not opening the Configuration screen.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the emulator supports accounts and market

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260868/android-emulator-trouble-creating-user-accounts

Comment: @Daniel : In that post he got atleast the next screen and couldn't connect with the server. In my case , there is no response at all from the Emulator after clicking ADD ACCOUNT.

ape : if it is not possible , then how can i test my app in the emulator. I dont have any device with me now.

Comment: You can emulate accounts, but you cannot use the account in real matters i believe. All though you should be able to connect to any Google Service, but your local account is limited and cannot register with e.g Google Play and such. What exactly is it you want to do? To test your application you need to push the apk to the emulator either from your IDE or CMD/Terminal.

Comment: What settings did you specify for your emulator? i had a similar problem, but i changed my android version from 4.2 to the google api's  17 and it worked for me, try that

Comment: I researched and exist a result on our site, Here link to reference [creating google account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260868/android-emulator-trouble-creating-user-accounts/4589234#4589234)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit late, but i'm putting this up for posterity.
I had a similar problem, it turned out that i had to use the google api's (17 to be specific) for the target settings when setting up the emulator, hope this will be of help to someone.

Comment: Helped me almost ten years later!