# Add Google Account to AVD - Receiving Error "the server requires security features your phone does not support"

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, galaxy-tab

I am trying to add Google account to Samsung Galaxy tab AVD .. but I am getting weird error - "the server requires security features your phone does not support"

I thought this is very basic thing so not sure what am i really missing.

**AVD Settings:**

Device: 10.1" WXGA (Tablet) (1280*800:mdpi)
Target: GALAXY Tab Addon (Samsung Electronic Co. Ltd) - API Level 8
Internal Storage : 200 MiB
SD Card: 2048 MiB

From Account & Sync option, when I add account, put my gmail and password, it gives me a screen where it is asking me

Domain\Username :  \myusername@gmail.com
Password : *** 
server:   m.google.com 
Use Secure connection (SSL) - checked
Accept all SSL certificates - unchecked

Once I enter all this info click Next button,  I receive the error saying "the server requires security features your phone does not support"

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4589234/996313)

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to these :

http://ukblog.im-mobility.com/setting-microsoft-exchange-email-samsung-galaxy-s-iii

http://androidforums.com/xoom-support-troubleshooting/326127-exchange-server-requires-security-features-your-android-device-does-not-support.html

Also, could you try to use the mobile network in place of wifi.