# Unable to setup Google Account in Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, visual-studio-emulator

I am using visual studio android emulator and trying to set up Google account for playstore and some other purposes. Whenever i try to singin it gives me error msg shown in Fig. 1.[image: Fig. 1]

And when i click on next button it stuck on this screen.
[image]

I tried to manually login using browser and its working. Also when i give wrong password, it gives me error that "Username or password is incorrect", which means that problem is not with connection to server, it's something else. Any type of help will be appriciatd

Comment: I am not using android studio emulator, its visual studio emulator for android which is 1000 times faster even faster than genymotion.

Comment: Try this link may be it might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260868/android-emulator-trouble-creating-user-accounts