# How to remove specific permission when build Android app with gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, permissions

Recently Google auto merge permission from Google Service to final release apk.
Some one ask here [Why are permissions being automatically added to my AndroidManifest when including Google Play Services library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658439/why-are-permissions-being-automatically-added-to-my-androidmanifest-when-includi)

My problem is some permission don't need and I don't want some sensitive permission in my app. So how to remove permission like **android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** ?
With gradle build, I don't want to disable Manifest Merger. I read some where that can config Merger to remove permission from external lib, but I can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Add attribute `tools:node` with a value of `remove` to your manifest:

```xml
<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#node_markers

Don't forget to add the `tools` namespace to the root element of your manifest.