# Firebase and wake locks issue in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics, android-wake-lock

I'm using several Firebase products in an Android app:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
```

One or more of these products seems to be using the `WAKE_LOCK` permission. Possibly Analytics or FCM.

I can understand where it's needed. The problem however is that in the Google Play Console, in the Android Vitals section, Google warns me that the **Stuck partial wake locks** percentage is **2.30%** which is larger than the **Bad behavior threshold** which is **0.70%**. Similarly, the **Background stuck partial wake locks** is **1.40%** which is again larger than the **Bad behavior threshold** which is **0.10%**.

In other words, Google considers this number of wake locks a 'bad behavior'.

I don't use wake locks, so it seems that the issue is coming from the Firebase SDK.

Anyone knows what's causing that? Can we fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell where Android manifest items come from by using [Android Studio's Merged Manifest tab](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts) when viewing your app's manifest file.  When you view this on you manifest, you'll see that WAKE_LOCK comes from firebase-iid.

To find out what includes firebase-iid, you can use gradle to show a dependency graph.

```
./gradlew dependencies
```

The output of this shows that it's included by both firebase-core and firebase-messaging:

```
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.6.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:11.6.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license:11.6.0
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0
     \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.6.0
          +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
          +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
          +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:11.6.0
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
          |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.6.0 (*)
          |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
          |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:11.6.0
          \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:11.6.0
```

There is nothing here that needs to be "fixed".  Firebase simply makes use of wake locks to do its normal business.  You can always try to [remove the permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616334/how-to-remove-specific-permission-when-build-android-app-with-gradle), but then Firebase may not work correctly any more.  Just leave it alone.

Comment: There is definitely something that needs to be fixed, since Google flags this as **bad behavior**. There's also an official guide from Google that suggests possible solutions, mainly by using JobScheduler: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/wakelock.html

Comment: You're misunderstanding the message.  Usage of wake locks is not always bad.  __Incorrect__ usage of wake locks is bad.

Comment: The wake lock permission is not going away any time soon, but if you think that Firebase is provably at fault for anything, please file a bug report.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Of course wake locks are not always bad. However, Google flags this large number of wake locks as a 'bad behavior' in Android vitals. And 'bad behavior' issues affect the app ranking in the Play Store searches (_source: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/android-vitals.html_). They also suggest that when using wake locks, the app should be in the foreground, while Firebase Analytics seem to be using a wake lock to upload the data on the background. Again, I personally don't have a problem with that, however that is flagged as an issue in Google Play console.

Comment: In any case, I'll file a bug report