# Migrating to the New Places SDK Client ask for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission on Play Store

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, google-places-api

I have done Migration for Google place api to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

I am using methods.
`fetchPlace()`
`findAutocompletePredictions()`

But not `findCurrentPlace()`
And I also not gave permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in manifest or anywhere else.

But while i am trying to update app on Play Store. it gives me warning message.

New permissions added
Warning:
Users that have the APK with version code 17 may need to accept the `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, which may result in them not upgrading to this version of the app.

Why it will ask for the permission to user, i have't add any feature which will ask user for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission.

Please guide me in case i am doing or understanding anything wrong.

Here are the permission which is added in menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportVersion"
//    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01"

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation project(':cardlib')


    implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.7'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

    //Google Liabrary
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    //New Place integration
        implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //Lottie
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.0-beta1'

    //Retrofit and Json Parsing
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'

    //Chunk Interpretor (For Debug only)
    debugImplementation 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library:1.1.0'
    releaseImplementation 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library-no-op:1.1.0'

    //Room components
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    //FABRIC
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Mix Panel
    implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.+'

    //Branch IO
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'

    // Paytm
    implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.3.1') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    implementation 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.takusemba:spotlight:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.39.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.39.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:4.39.0'
    implementation 'com.bitly:bitlysdk:+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.5'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:razorpay-java:1.3.8'
    implementation project(':StackLayoutManager')





}
```

Comment: Are you certain you haven't added findCurrentPlace() anywhere in your app and that you've fully migrated to the new Places SDK? Are you using any other libraries that could be automatically requesting this permission? Please post your manifest and build.gradle.

Comment: Yes , i haven't add findCurrentPlace() anywhere. if i upload APK with older version of Place Api it does not give me any warnings and i also don't have any functionality which ask for Location permission.

Comment: i have also added permission used in menifest and gradle.

Comment: I see. What's the version of your device?

Comment: I have Marsh-mellow, Nogut and Orio device.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your quick answers. I'm investigating this on my end, will get back to you next week!

Answer (score 1):

The Places SDK adds all the permissions it needs to its manifest, which gets merged in with yours when your app is built.  You can explicitly remove any permissions you don't want.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31616334) other answer shows how:

```
<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```