# How do I remove Query_all_permissions in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hey guys my app has been rejected from the Google play store 3 times now, I've gone into the release merge manifest and deleted the query_all_permissions a bunch of times but everytime I build the app bundle it gets readded and Google Play won't budge when I ask for permission to use it. I've tried replacing it with other permissions also but that doesn't work. I'm not sure what dependency keeps adding it back if that's what's going on or how to find out which one. The dependencies I currently have are

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
cloud_firestore: ^4.5.0
firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
flutterfire_ui: ^0.4.3+20
fluttertoast: ^8.1.1
image_picker: ^0.8.7+5
firebase_storage: ^11.2.0
firebase_core: ^2.3.0-beta
url_launcher: ^6.1.11
```

I'm unsure how to remove it, anything helps as I want to upload my app to the google play store as soon as possible, thank you! My Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thriving_in_the_modern_world"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.0.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <!-- Permissions options for the `notification` group -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>

        <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
    </queries> <!-- Required by older versions of Google Play services to create IID tokens -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.thriving_in_the_modern_world.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.thriving_in_the_modern_world.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION" />

    <application
        android:name="android.app.Application"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icons"
        android:label="Thrive"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.thriving_in_the_modern_world.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

            <!--
                 Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.dynamiclinks.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.internal.FirebaseDynamicLinkRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.storage.StorageRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.thriving_in_the_modern_world.flutterfirebasemessaginginitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="99" />
        <provider
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.thriving_in_the_modern_world.flutter.image_provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/flutter_image_picker_file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.maru.twitter_login.chrome_custom_tabs.ChromeCustomTabsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="firebase.auth"
                    android:path="/"
                    android:scheme="genericidp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="firebase.auth"
                    android:path="/"
                    android:scheme="recaptcha" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="cct.com.thriving_in_the_modern_world"
                    android:scheme="fbconnect" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--
            Service handling Google Sign-In user revocation. For apps that do not integrate with
            Google Sign-In, this service will never be started.
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION"
            android:visibleToInstantApps="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--
             FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             but set to not exported to explicitly avoid allowing another app to call it.
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.thriving_in_the_modern_world.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!--
         The initialization ContentProvider will call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize automatically
         with the application context. This config is merged in with the host app's manifest,
         but there can only be one provider with the same authority activated at any given
         point; so if the end user has two or more different apps that use Facebook SDK, only the
         first one will be able to use the provider. To work around this problem, we use the
         following placeholder in the authority to identify each host application as if it was
         a completely different provider.
        -->
        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.thriving_in_the_modern_world.FacebookInitProvider"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.facebook.CurrentAccessTokenExpirationBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ACTION_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.facebook.AuthenticationTokenManager$CurrentAuthenticationTokenChangedBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ACTION_CURRENT_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="backend:com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctBackendFactory"
                android:value="cct" />
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="com.thriving_in_the_modern_world.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>

        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.DUMP" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.INSTALL_PROFILE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SKIP_FILE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SAVE_PROFILE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.BENCHMARK_OPERATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You can force remove the permission by editing Flutter app's AndroidManifest, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616472/1860868

Comment: @DerekK Unfortunately whenever I build the manifest gets reset and the tools:node="remove" is removed, I'm trying to read the logs to figure out why but it's hard to follow. Edit I may have figured it out, there's a root androidmanifest in android->app->src -> main I added it to, if that worked thanks guys!

Comment: Exactly, you must put it into the app->src -> main manifest, which is not re-generated on build.

Comment: @DerekK yeah that makes sense I was putting it in the Manifests in the merge manifest, I realized when I was reading the manifest logs that there was a main manifest lol. Thank you!

Comment: @DerekK I've uploaded the new .aab to google play and keep getting flagged for Query_all_packages permission and I don't see it anywhere in my android manifests (Even done a ctrl-find), I've tried to appeal also but got rejected, do you know why?

Comment: I did a flutter clean then pub get before building the app bundle instead of just deleting it I'll see if that helps

Comment: If you have also test tracks make sure to update them as well (e.g. closed or beta testing). Unfortunately many Google Play rejections are unclear, you're not alone...