# Google Play Store: App does not require any additional special permissions

Tags: android, google-play

Play Store update apps automatically if there are no change in permissions. But skype asked me to update app and when I clicked on update button I found this popup.

[image]

So if there is no permission changed then why play-store showing this dialog.

Actually I developed an app and in that app I did not change any permissions and got same dialog, checked their documentations related to automatic updates but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

This happen to me too, and it took a bit of debugging to figure out. If you go to the app page (before clicking update), and scroll to the very bottom, there is a link to "Permission Details". In my case, it showed "Use accounts on the device", which corresponded to `android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS`. You may have a different permission, but if you have the same new one as mine, read on for how I debugged and fixed it.

I didn't add this permission, but doing a grep of my entire build, I saw:
`./app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-wallet/8.3.0/AndroidManifest.xml: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>`

So I suspect some update to google-play-services (or perhaps moving from selective API includes to the whole API include, as delineated in https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) caused me to use the google-play-services file and it's AndroidManifest.xml dependencies, including this new permission I never needed. There's more information on this in: [Why are permissions being automatically added to my AndroidManifest when including Google Play Services library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658439/why-are-permissions-being-automatically-added-to-my-androidmanifest-when-includi)

By going back to using individual google-play-services packages, I was able to remove Wallet and it's USE_CREDENTIALS, which should help make my installs seamless again.

Incidentally, Android 6.0 Marshmellow removed this permission entirely (see [USE_CREDENTIALS not available in new Android M API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338764/use-credentials-not-available-in-new-android-m-api) ), so maybe that has something to do with it? Where Wallet started depending on it automatically in some recent-or-not-so-recent update, since they assumed it'd be automatic in Marshmellow builds, and some apps are now including the permission dependency without being aware of it?