# USE_CREDENTIALS not available in new Android M API

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

While trying new permissions API, notably:

ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions

for permission:

android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS

(whichn is not listed as "normal" permission)

I've received an "unknown permissionn exception".

Is it a bug? Or is USE_CREDENTIALS a normal permission after all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. `USE_CREDENTIALS` was removed from the Android SDK in Android 6.0. Not only will you not find it [in `Manifest.permission` in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html), but if you try hunting for it on an Android 6.0 device (by enumerating all permissions via `PackageManager`), it does not seem to show up.