# What permissions are needed by each Google Play Services component?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-permissions

As I found out in [Why are permissions being automatically added to my AndroidManifest when including Google Play Services library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658439/why-are-permissions-being-automatically-added-to-my-androidmanifest-when-includi), various Google Play Services components implicitly add permissions to your app starting in Google Play Services 7.5. But obviously not all components require the same permissions - for instance, play-services-games:7.8.0 doesn't require any.

Is there an easy way to tell what permissions will be added by a particular Google Play Services component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit `$ANDROID_SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/gms`. In there, choose your desired artifact (e.g., `play-services-maps`) and version (e.g., `8.1.0`). Open up the AAR in your favorite ZIP utility, and look at the `AndroidManifest.xml` file published in there, to see if there are `<uses-permission>` elements. Then, open up the POM file, see what dependencies there are, and repeat the process for the AARs for those dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this excellent article](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/how-libraries-can-silently-add-permissions-to-your-android-app-620911d7de6c), you can see the final manifest file created during the build process here;

```
app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

You can also see a report that shows where every permission comes from;

```
app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt
```

You can use a line like this in your manifest to **remove** any extra permissions you want (but be careful! you might break functionality);

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove"/>
```