# Google Play Error code "-504"

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I'm facing an annoying issue with Google Play over and over again. There are some apps (currently Deezer and Teamtreehouse) which can't be updated/installed due this error:

**"Can't install App" (Error code: -504)**

FYI: This is not a 504 but negative 504 error

The only working solution what I found is the factory reset an wiping the whole phone, which is really annoying doing this every month. My question is, someone has easier solution for this error?

I have tried all solution what I found:

- force stopping play store / play store framework
- clearing data
- clearing cache of google play store & google service framework
- removing  gmail account
- side-loading apps
- directly installing apks
- searching apps related files on phone and removing them

[The image URL of the error](http://oi67.tinypic.com/b67qsw.jpg)

My phone details:
Xperia M4 Aqua

Android 5.0

Comment: I don't think your question fits the scope of StackOverflow as [defined in the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), since it is in no way related to programming or software development. You're probably better off on [android.stackexchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I disagree. If changes to your code is what caused this issue to happen during Play Store builds it would be helpful to know and understand what could cause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is caused by linking the app to SD card.

This is what worked for me:

1. `Move` (not Link) the app to SD card
2. After you've moved the app to SD card, `Move` it back to Phone
3. Now you can update the app via App Store and link back to SD card if you want.

**FYI:** You must repeat this process every-time you want update the app.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error for my app once. 
(I downgraded my play-services library to a lower version and that error occurred when my users try to upgrade my app from play store.)

I downgraded from

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

The reason why I tried to downgrade is because the newer versions of the play-services added a whole bunch of permissions automatically (see [Why are permissions being automatically added to my AndroidManifest when including Google Play Services library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658439/why-are-permissions-being-automatically-added-to-my-androidmanifest-when-includi)).

The problem is with the app rather than your phone, they will have to do the fix on their end. I switched back to the newer version of the library.

as an interim solution - uninstalling the app and reinstalling it works for my app.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error occur recently in my app. But only for all < 8.0 devices. It worked fine on 8.0. It ended up being because a new service I added had capital letters in the service name.