# prevent showing chooser dialog each time get user account

Tags: android, user-accounts, android-intent-chooser

I need to check user account in my app and I need to  check it more than once in app , I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34653406/2758345) and works fine , but the problem is each time I want to get account  the chooser dialog appears for " choose an account " and its not good at all , I appreciate any solution for stopping that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using account picker  so you should not expect that dialog not appear