# Using GMail API on Android without having to use GET_ACCOUNTS permission

Tags: android, gmail, gmail-api

Just a quick snippet of my code:

Initialize:

```
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), SCOPES)
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
```

Then I start the chooser:

```
startActivityForResult(mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
```

Then in the ActivityForResult

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        PersistentUtil.persistGmailName(this, accountName);
                        mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                        checkDataAccess();
                    }
                }
```

Where checkDataAccess:

```
java.lang.Thread thread = new java.lang.Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            Gmail mService = new com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
                    .setApplicationName(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .build();

            try {
                Gmail.Users users = mService.users();
                Gmail.Users.Messages messages = users.messages();
                Gmail.Users.Messages.List me = messages.list("me");
                ListMessagesResponse temp = me.execute();
                // if no error is thrown then, we are good to go
                onGmailFinished();
                //                    parseMessageList(mService, temp);
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                startActivityForResult(
                        ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) e).getIntent(),
                        REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
```

**ISSUE**

`ListMessagesResponse temp = me.execute();` will eventually call a `getAccounts()` method which searches for the user in the accounts that are configured on the device. It'll return null, if the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission is not granted.

HOW can I make it so that I don't depend on the GET_ACCOUNTS permission, some way of configuring a gmail account independently of the device's accounts? I don't want to request the GET_ACCOUNTS permission.

Is there a way of doing this or do I always have to go via the intentChooser and depend on the GET_ACCOUNTS permission afterwards ? :(

Answer (score 0):

It says from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502017/getting-android-owners-email-address-nicely/19444640#19444640) that it is better to use an [Account Picker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker) wherein it returns an intent to an `Activity` that prompts the user to choose from a list of accounts.

> If your app has the **GET_ACCOUNTS** permission and there's only one
>   account, you get it right away. If your app doesn't have it, or if
>   there are more than one account, users get a prompt so they can
>   authorize or not the action.

Your app needs to include the **Google Play Services** but it doesn't need any permissions.

Basic code sample:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_EMAIL = 1;
private TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

// ...

try {
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
            new String[] { GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE }, false, null, null, null, null);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_EMAIL);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO
}

// ...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EMAIL && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        email.setText(accountName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems your only retrieving the email ... my intention is to have access to the users's gmail accounts

Comment: Yes, you could try that to get the gmail account.