# How to get user name and email address from android device like Google Pay app

Tags: java, android, google-signin, google-pay

Is there any way to **Prefill** the email address and username from an android device similar to Google Pay Application.

As Google pay application is not taking any permissions or Google sign Options or Account pickers(that user will select one of his available accounts).

Can someone help/suggest how to get this.

Attaching a screenshot for reference.[image from Google Pay app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqViG.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59373332/3995941

Comment: Hi @Deepak, thanks for the quick response, in the above suggestion there is permission required "GET_ACCOUNTS", can we do it with out asking any permission.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)

Comment: Hi @AjayKS, thanks for the quick response, in the above suggestion all the answers requests for runtime permissions like "READ_CONTACTS", "GET_ACCOUNTS", account pickers, can we do it with out asking any permission or popup to choose an account.

Comment: No, You have to need permission. if you are looking at google, Google have phone root permission SO they don't need any Account permission (except other)

Comment: Any hacks or work arounds to implement this?

Comment: in rooted device

Comment: Both in rooted and non-rooted devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AccountPicker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker).

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19444640/5603322).

Comment: can we get the details without any AccountPicker, that's what my question is.