# How can i get the profile image from my gmail account in android

Tags: android, gmail, contacts

I am currently working with an application which has to set a profile image. Can I set the profile image from my primary Gmail account profile image? Recently I've seen an application like that working this way. It takes my profile image of primary Gmail account and sets it in their application. Is it possible to do this? Give me some reference codes please.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Google + API for this see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10599565/1051147)

All this urls fetch the profile picture of a user:

```
https://www.google.com/s2/photos/profile/{user_id}
https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/{user_id}
https://profiles.google.com/s2/photos/profile/{user_id}
```

Comment: how we can get the user id of Google plus,without any api integration