# How do i retrieve the email address when using google auth in mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have enabled Google Auth only within my asp.net mvc 5 app.
I see that when I am redirected to googles auth screen I am asking for permission to view the users name and email address. I then return from Google, log in, and name my new user.

I have obviously asked for permission to view the email address, but by default this is not stored. How would I store this in the users table?

I have tried editing the options in startup.auth, but there aren't any pertaining to the email. When doing this via oAuth you manually ask for it. I just don't know where exactly I should be asking for the email address...

Also how would I go about asking for their google account picture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can retrieve it from ClaimIdentity as an Email Claim

[Check this example](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2013/10/03/decoupling-owin-external-authentication-from-asp-net-identity.aspx)

`var email = externalIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937553/get-extradata-from-mvc5-framework-oauth-owin-identity-provider-with-external-aut/18833978#18833978

Comment: FindFirstValue method does not exist. In which namespace can I find it?

Comment: its in my IdentityConfig.cs in App_Start in my project

Answer (score 8):

Full code in aspnet mvc5

```
var googleOption=new GoogleAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Provider = new GoogleAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated =  (context) =>
        {
            var rawUserObjectFromFacebookAsJson = context.Identity;
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:google:name", context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:google:email", context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
     }
};

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOption);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)