# How can I access a user's openId/OAuth avatar and email address in MVC5?

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-mvc-5

I want my website to automatically add the user's email address and avatar when they register via OpenId or OAuth. MVC 5 allows a user to register and login with their openId Google, Facebook, or Twitter account, however it doesn't seem to pass any of the linked information back to the website.

I already have a user profile model that gets created when the user registers, but I would like to be able to add their Email address and avitar without having to ask them for it. How can I access the user's linked avatar and email address that is associated with their Google/Facebook/Twitter account once they register through an openId?

So far the information I have found and tried seems to be applicable to MVC 4 or the release candidate of MVC 5 and doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the exact same question over here :

[How do i retrieve the email address when using google auth in mvc 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369129/how-do-i-retrieve-the-email-address-when-using-google-auth-in-mvc-5)

credit goes to jd4u for the answer

> You can retrieve it from ClaimIdentity as an Email Claim
>
> Check this example
>
> ```
> var email = externalIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
> ```

Regarding the profile pic, once again jd4u pointed me to :

[Get ExtraData from MVC5 framework OAuth/OWin identity provider with external auth provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937553/get-extradata-from-mvc5-framework-oauth-owin-identity-provider-with-external-aut/18833978#18833978)

I ended up using their gravatar image instead, as it seemed less work. And thats what gravatar is for anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/) it's pretty easy to implement and you may retrieve more images.

From their site....

> An "avatar" is an image that represents you online—a little picture that appears next to your name when you interact with websites. A Gravatar is a Globally Recognized Avatar. You upload it and create your profile just once, and then when you participate in any Gravatar-enabled site, your Gravatar image will automatically follow you there.
>   Gravatar is a free service for site owners, developers, and users. It is automatically included in every WordPress.com account and is run and supported by Automattic.

Comment: I already use Gravitar, it works fine, I just wanted to include more people, since not everyone has a linked gravitar account. Thanks, though.