# Google authentification get email MVC5

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-5

How to obtain the external user email (the one authentificated by google), firstname and name in my ASP.NET MVC5 website.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369129/how-do-i-retrieve-the-email-address-when-using-google-auth-in-mvc-5)
All credit to jd4u for his answer

```
var email = externalIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

the findFirstValue method looks like this :

```
 public static string FindFirstValue(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string claimType) 
    {
        Claim claim = identity.FindFirst(claimType);
        if (claim != null) 
        {
            return claim.Value;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Getting an error that FindFirstValue method does not exist in compiler in VS2013?

Comment: updated with the findfirstvalue method. its in my IdentityConfig.cs in App_Start in my project

Comment: Oh, so this was a self-made method? Okay.

Comment: @PussInBoots [FindFirstValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityextensions.findfirstvalue%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) is not a self-made method. It's an extension method, part of `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions` (along with `GetUserId` and `GetUserName`.) If you are getting a *method does not exist* error, it is because you need to import Microsoft.AspNet.Identity namespace (i.e. add `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;` at the top of your class.)