# Extract user-email from external login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm just started to working with MVC5.

I'm made a small web-application that allow the users to connect with thier Facebook/Google/Microsoft account.

It's working nice, but, the created user (in DB) is missing their account email addresses (NULL).

This is how user looks like in my application:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

My account controller is pretty similar to vs2013 default mvc5 web-application template.

How I'm can get their email addresses from those specific providers (Facebook/Google/Microsoft)?

Answer (score 0):

[How do i retrieve the email address when using google auth in mvc 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369129/how-do-i-retrieve-the-email-address-when-using-google-auth-in-mvc-5)

credit to jd4u for the answer :

```
var email = externalIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2013/10/03/decoupling-owin-external-authentication-from-asp-net-identity.aspx