# Authentication and getting extra data from external Providers. Visual Basic behind code ASP.NET VS 2013

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oauth

I have a VS 2013 project using Entity framework with webforms and MVC.  I have been struggling to find VB.NET code that will retrieve extra data from the external provider when I use google or other external logins.  There is plenty of comments in c# code for this, specifically article(s):-

[How do i retrieve the email address when using google auth in mvc 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369129/how-do-i-retrieve-the-email-address-when-using-google-auth-in-mvc-5/21778533#21778533)

[Getting the email from external providers Google and Facebook during account association step in a default MVC5 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378043/getting-the-email-from-external-providers-google-and-facebook-during-account-ass/20379623#20379623)

Well I have an answer and thought I'd share it.
Placed in the login.aspx.vb file.
Having authenticated the login you can use the following to get the extra data such as email

```
If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then

    Dim verifiedloginInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo(IdentityHelper.XsrfKey, User.Identity.GetUserId())

    Dim externalIdentity = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)
    Dim emailClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(Function(c) c.Type = ClaimTypes.Email)
    Dim email = emailClaim.Value

    MsgBox(email)

end if
```

Apologies for breaking the forum etiquette but as a newbie I can’t comment on other posts.. what’s a boy to do.
Special thanks to this utility http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx>

Comment: REVIEW: Removed the code from login.aspx.vb and inserted into RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.vb.  This enabled me to allow athentication of the user by social media, validate the username, create a user.  Hand add the claim value(s) for email to the new user profile.

Comment: So behind the Login_click call I placed:-  
`
  IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, False)
  Dim externalIdentity = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)
  Dim emailClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(Function(c) c.Type = ClaimTypes.Email)
  If manager.AddClaim(user.Id, emailClaim).Succeeded Then
    ‘ Add anything extra here if you wish
  else
    ‘ Add extra here if you wish
  End If
          IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response) `  
Hope this helps others