# Using MVC5 GoogleAuthenticationOptions to get extra user profile information during authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get a user's date of birth and avatar/icon/photo/picture when he or she logs into my MVC5 site with a Google account.

I've read this:

[Get ExtraData from MVC5 framework OAuth/OWin identity provider with external auth provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937553/get-extradata-from-mvc5-framework-oauth-owin-identity-provider-with-external-aut/18833978#18833978)

but it doesn't make much sense ...  ... am I suppose to know this?

In my Startup.Auth.cs file i have this snippet:

```
var gProvider = new GoogleAuthenticationProvider { OnAuthenticated = context => { var claims = context.Identity.Claims.ToList(); return Task.FromResult(0); } };
var gOptions = new GoogleAuthenticationOptions { Provider = gProvider };
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(gOptions);
```

The claims variable contains 5 items: (each item starts with 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/')

```
0: { nameidentifier: https://www.google.com/accounts/.../id?id... }
1: { givenname: Benjamin }
2: { surname: Day }
3: { name: Benjamin Day }
4: { emailaddress: ben@sillypenguin.net }
```

Can anyone help point out what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing to get the extra profile data I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4):

if in short, you have to use OAuth 2.0 integration with Google instead of Open ID that enabled by default.

```
public class CustomGoogleProvider : GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task Authenticated(GoogleOAuth2AuthenticatedContext context)
    {
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", context.User.GetValue("picture").ToString()));
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("profile", context.User.GetValue("profile").ToString()));

        return base.Authenticated(context);
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
    var googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "{{Your Client Id}}",
        ClientSecret = "{{Your Client Secret}}",
        CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalGoogleLoginCallback"),
        Provider = new CustomGoogleProvider(),
    };

    googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions);
```

I described the process in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937553/get-extradata-from-mvc5-framework-oauth-owin-identity-provider-with-external-aut/22694372#22694372)