# ASP.NET Identity Google Callbackpath throwing internal server error 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I am trying to configure google authentication in my existing asp.net mvc 5 application using Identity 2.0.

In Startup.Auth i have configured the google authentication options like so.

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = ".....",
    ClientSecret = ".....",
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLoginCallback")
}
```

In trying to test the callback manually in my browser I tried to navigate to the CallbackPath url and was presented with a blank screen and a 500 internal server error in the developer console.

I am positive this error is occuring within the OWIN middleware because if i change the CallbackPath to any other value I am able to navigate to the original path.

I can find no error events or logs or any other information in the console to help me understand why.

Can anymore help my in the right direction?

Update: this is the response I am getting

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 25 Feb 2015 07:37:18 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you dont have to specify the callback url here but, log into your google console then activate the Google+ API and configure the Callback url.

You can refer to this url-

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/07/02/changes-to-google-oauth-2-0-and-updates-in-google-middleware-for-3-0-0-rc-release.aspx

This SO question has the same answer-
[Google Authentication using OWIN Oauth in MVC5 not hitting ExternalLoginCallback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072786/google-authentication-using-owin-oauth-in-mvc5-not-hitting-externallogincallback)

Comment: I have gone through that post, removed the Callbackpath, updated the Google developer console to accept /signin-google and created a route for signin-google to Account/ExternalLoginCallback. Still the same result.