# Is it possible to create an avatar/profile picture link from a Google+ ID?

Tags: api, google-plus

Is it possible to convert a Google+ ID (e.g. 104629419698573857134) into a link to its profile picture? Without making any API calls?

With Facebook its easy e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/564082465/picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://profiles.google.com/s2/u/0/photos/profile/[[ USER ID]]

Google plus doesn't support size parameter like Facebook Graph

Example

http://profiles.google.com/s2/u/0/photos/profile/106754536592514321880

Comment: It turns out you can use the sz=50 (or whatever) parameter to get different sizes

Comment: Sadly this no longer seems to work, if you know the new version and could edit this answer that would be appreciated :)

Comment: Indeed, the functionality stopped working as of early March 2014: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11230629/438886