# Getting YouTube channel profile picture with channelId

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

So I'm trying to get the channel profile picture for a YouTube channel by using the channelId.

I would like to do it simply by adding the channelId to a URL and get the image that way.
Facebook has something similar where you use this URL:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?type=square
```

Google+ has it too, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128700/getting-google-profile-picture-url-with-user-id) question here. Sadly it didn't work for YouTube (I couldn't get it to work)

Hope someone has a solution!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'd like to know this, with the new APIs.

Comment: It really is a shame this is still a problem. There should be a standardized method to access channel thumbnails using only the channel ID. The same as you can access YouTube thumbnails. There is *no* reason to require an API request for this specific action.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) request for that.

In response you will get [snippet.thumbnails."default".url](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.thumbnails.%28key%29) for that

For authenticated user's channel:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Fthumbnails&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Or for any channel ID:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id+CHANNEL_ID&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Fthumbnails&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: That would work, but I'm currently receiving a users home feed. I would just like to display the channel image of the channel who posted the update. Sending a separate request for each response is a lot of work, and there has to be an easier way..?

Comment: For your 2nd answer "for any channel ID" I'm receiving the error: "No filter selected. Expected one of: mySubscribers, categoryId, forUsername, id, idParam, mine, managedByMe"

Comment: @pas13's answer worked for me when I added my API key.

Comment: `&id+CHANNEL_ID&` ought to be `&id=CHANNEL_ID&`.

Answer (score 9):

a little bit late, but maybe interesting for others:

just create a comma separated list for the different channelIds and then call

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id='+commaSeperatedList+'&fields=items(id%2Csnippet%2Fthumbnails)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

therefore you don't have to send a request for each item

Comment: This answer work as long as you add a parameter with your api key. `&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Comment: is that possible to get the profile picture of the any YouTube creator ??
The information only I have is any one video from the respective channel ?

Answer (score 8):

In PHP, I got it with:

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Fthumbnails%2Fdefault&id={$channelId}&key={$API}";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$channelOBJ = json_decode( curl_exec( $ch ) );

$thumbnail_url = $channelOBJ->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->default->url;
```