# Getting Google+ profile name with user_id

Tags: google-api, google-plus

Is It possible like https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/?sz= to get user name by user_id?
Without oAuth, without any code, only URL.
I'm trying to use in Spreadseet in formula =HYPERLINK()
Thanks!

Comment: like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128700/getting-google-profile-picture-url-with-user-id

Comment: I assume you already have the user ID? What spreadsheet app are you using?

Comment: Yes, see example http://goo.gl/gncnZR

Comment: Are you opposed to using Google App Script?

Comment: BrettJ, oh, I'm not! I can use a Goole Apps Script. It's best idea. But I thought a simple url is available ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read a value, such as a name, from a URL without some sort of helper method like a Google App Script. The built in spreadsheet functions (like ImportHtml) aren't going to provide you that capability. Of course every user has a a URL: https://plus.google.com/114173154718145483119 for example, but you still would need to parse that page for the title. And if you're going to hit a URL, you should do it the right way and just use the API within App Script using [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get), which does allow for anonymous access if you have specific user IDs to look up so that you would not need to set up OAuth authentication.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you only have the profile image links? These do not follow any pattern than I am aware of that you can use to determine who the owner is - it does not look like you could easily link the content to a specific user. You could search for pages containing the path but this would be error-prone.

However, if you have the path to a user's Google+ account, then you can extract their profile id and can then perform an [API call to plus/people/get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=109716647623830091721&_h=2&)

The format of the path to a user's Google+ profile is as follows:

https://plus.google.com/[profileid]

Comment: I can use an API, I know this! I look for a simple way!

Comment: I can use Google Apps Script for to get name.