# Google account image from email

Tags: gravatar, google-account

Is it possible to retrieve a Google account profile image like a Gravatar image?

I'm thinking it would be very handy to make a failover to Google image, if a gravatar is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to get the Google user_id, you can [retrieve the Google+ image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128700/getting-google-profile-picture-url-with-user-id).

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be an easy way to [get the user_id from an email address](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=64).