# Unable to fetch GPlus profile pic. Is the Google Plus Image fetch URL updated?

Tags: android, google-plus

It's weird, but till yesterday i was able to get the gplus user's image in my app but today it's just not coming. Nothing simply blank. And just appears at some time..

I have been using the urls specified in [Getting Google+ profile picture url with user_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128700/getting-google-profile-picture-url-with-user-id) but these all seem invalid and gives **404 Error**.

https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/116018066779980863044?sz=100

If anybody could help me out why this weird behaviour. The Profile pic appears seldom. But mostly it's blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image URL you were using was never a public API and so there was no guarantee it would continue to work. The recommended practice going forward is to use the [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) API method to get the `profile` => `image` => `url` value instead. That URL could stop working if the user changes their avatar so you might want to fetch the actual image and cache it on your own servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Image url has been updated.

Inorder to get that, we can use the PlusClient objects methods:

```
imageURL = mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson().getImage().getUrl()
{Returns a String - Image Url as String}

imageURL = mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson().getImage()
{Returns an instance of Image object}
```