# How can I upload a profile picture to Google Plus via API?

Tags: rest, file-upload, google-plus

I'm trying to build a system which has a tool to upload profile picture to other networks. Twitter have an API point for it, Facebook have some "tricks", but my question is: there is a way to make this on Google +?

I checked the API (https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/) and didn't found anything, but at Facebook, for example, I can post the picture to a specific album and then send the user to an window to redefine the profile pic. In Google+ I've this option too? What else I can do in this case?

I found something older that permits the upload of new pictures at a Google Apps Profile (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/#Updating). Maybe this is the path but, as far as I know, the Google+ is the new Google Profile =\

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128700/getting-google-profile-picture-url-with-user-id

Comment: They only say things about getting image (method: GET). I want to upload something via api (method: PUT/POST). This method that you posted works for uploading too?