# How to get gmail social avatar using social-auth-app-django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-socialauth

I googled and got some helpful link for getting gmail avatar. I used **social-auth-app-django** library and following the 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575713/retrieving-profile-picture-from-google-and-facebook-in-python-social-auth) to setup functionality. Authentication works fine but stuck in getting avatar.I created **pipeline.py** inside project main configured root and called this inside my view like as **from TestDjangoAuth.pipeline import get_avatar**.
Is this the right way i'm going through to retrieve the avatar? Another query is how to use the pipeline method in views.py like **user_details**, **get_username** that we called in **SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE**

This is the redirect method in views.py which gives some error. i wanna set avatar as session:

```
from TestDjangoAuth.pipeline import get_avatar
def social_login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            request.session['photo'] = get_avatar()
```

This the **pipeline.py** that i modified to use in my view

```
def get_avatar(backend, strategy, details, response, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    url = None
    if backend.name == 'google-oauth2':
        url = response['image'].get('url')

    print(url)
    return url
```

When i return url to use in my view to use profile picture this gives the following error

```
AttributeError at /auth/complete/google-oauth2/

'str' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem using below code snippet by googling and applying some modification.

```
def get_avatar(request, backend, strategy, details, response, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    url = None
    # if backend.name == 'facebook':
    #     url = "http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large"%response['id']
    # if backend.name == 'twitter':
    #     url = response.get('profile_image_url', '').replace('_normal','')
    if backend.name == 'google-oauth2':
        try:
            url = response["picture"]
        except KeyError:
            url = response['image'].get('url')

        get_file = download(url)
        file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
        extension = 'jpeg'

        f = BytesIO(get_file)
        out = BytesIO()

        image = Image.open(f)
        image.save(out, extension)

def download(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        if not r.status_code == 200:
            raise Exception('file request failed with status code: ' + str(r.status_code))
        return (r.content)
    except Exception as ex:
        return ('error')
```