# How get user avatar with gmail api in swift

Tags: ios, swift, profile, gmail-api, avatar

I was reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128700/getting-google-profile-picture-url-with-user-id#22532031), but for this I need to know the userid

I need to bring the avatar of users who have sent me an email, but they have only the name and email, nothing more.

For example:

`GTLGmailMessagePartHeader 0x7fbb1e1560d0: {name:"From" value:"nameUser <emailuser@mail.com>"}`

I came up with the idea of bringing the user information from email, but does not return the id.

[getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile)

```
{
  "emailAddress": string,
  "messagesTotal": integer,
  "threadsTotal": integer,
  "historyId": unsigned long
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With this option you don't need has apikey.

http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/youridoryouremail?alt=json

Answer (score 0):

Check out [obtaining user profile information](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtaininguserprofileinformation) in the Google Identity docs. It lists the main methods for getting profile information about the currently authenticated Google user depending on the method of authentication your application is using.

- Google Sign-In uses [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get)
- OpenID Connect uses [people.getOpenIdConnect](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/getOpenIdConnect)