# http:403 forbidden error when trying to load img src with google profile pic

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-signin

hello everyone I am trying to load google profile picture in my site and other ones

I have done

```
var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
profile.getImageUrl()
```

when I sign in with google and save the image url to a database but when I try to put it into the src of an img tag like so

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = image;
img.alt = "image";
img.style.float = "left";
divn.appendChild(img);
```

I get 403 forbidden error sometimes, but sometimes it works
here is a sample link that I'm using the one that is stored in the database just altered a bit

```
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-OmV9386WzGk/AAAAFFFFAAI/AAAAAAAACpc/BEtVNh85tnk/s96-c/photo.jpg
```

so I'm just wondering if I'm doing it right obtaining the profile image, and its for other users also on the same page

Comment: 3 years later.. I'm facing the same issue.. did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No, i just decided to not use google sign in.

Comment: wow. March 2017 and still having this issue. if I figure it out, I'll answer the question. I really want to be able to use Google login.

Comment: Same issue .. 2018 .. Is this related to serving from localhost?

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using Firebase auth and that returns a picture url. It gives a 403 error sometimes.

Comment: I think this has to do with localhost. When I reload the page (so they page is serverside rendered) the picture shows. So there's some CORS issue probably.

Comment: For me it's also related to localhost, when I'm on my firebase domain it works.

Comment: 2020 same issue, now I'm using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, and works fine

Comment: October 2021 still same issue. But @Davide solution using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost still works

Comment: 2023, here we go again…

Answer (score 206):

Using [`referrerpolicy="no-referrer"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-referrerpolicy) seems to help. While it didn't work in a localhost app (before I added this attribute), it worked consistently when loading the image in its own tab. One of the differences in the request headers was the absence of `referer`.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Where in my code do I actually "use" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" ?  I use firebase in react to log through google login.  thnx for any help on this !

Comment: If you click the link in the answer, it takes you to the list of attributes for the IMG element. Simply add `referrerpolicy="no-referrer"` to your image elements that use googleusercontent.com

Comment: Note for REACT users: You'll need to camelCase the attribute name:  `referrerPolicy="no-referrer"`

Comment: This is what I needed to display custom emotes from YouTube (yt3.ggpht... URLs.) Thanks

Comment: This works in Chrome and Firefox, but it seems like Safari on both MacOS and iOS aren't working for me with this fix.

Answer (score 104):

Add `referrerpolicy="no-referrer"` attribute

```
<img src="your-google-link-here" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
```

[See about referrerpolicy here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)

Answer (score 14):

The only thing that worked for me was adding in

`<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />`

to the `head` of my html, as explained here: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/5909

Comment: This worked for me. I added it in the index.html of a Vuejs App.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this error when accessing the localhost without any protocol mentioned. If your images aren't loading, try reopening the website giving http:// or https://
That should solve the issue

Comment: This is correct. To test this I started a ngrok.io tunnel and the image was loading through the tunnel even though it was not working in localhost.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like google doesn't serve requests when the Referer header is set to localhost.
I changed it in the inspecto to some other domain, resent it and it worked.
I could even get the profile picture with curl and zero headers.

Answer (score 2):

2021 same issue

If you are using the CORS plugin on browser(chrome), please turn it off.

After off the plugin, restart your browser and try again.

.. it works for me!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same error in my Next.js app while rendering the user profile picture on MUI `<Avatar />` component.

It got fixed and picture was rendered correctly after adding this line on `_app.js`

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine that the URL is dynamically created each time you request it. That is supported by the fact that the user needs to be authenticated to retrieve [that URL](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people).
(If the user e.g. signs out of a previously authorized service / revokes the authentication, a service should no longer be able to retrieve the profile picture)

So either you store the entire image as a blob in the database or authenticate and use the User Object each time to request the URL.

Also, consider using the API as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128700/getting-google-profile-picture-url-with-user-id).

Comment: The URL is NOT dynamic. Please check my answer above

Answer (score 0):

The link sent back is NOT dynamic. For example my profile picture is this one:

> https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mB9nRJ8QQy4bJ97P2zeqX_5u7bVuS_DzxOsV0u6rlc

And I can see my photo even in an incognito tab and while I am logged off.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this in one of my projects, the issue was that I had been using the wrong img tag, i.e. `<img src"foo.png" />` instead of `<img src="foo.png></img>`. The latter is appropriate for DOCTYPE=HTML, whereas the former is meant for XHTML pages.

Answer (score -2):

Yup...there's a small hack to fix this. Just change your  tag to a closing one, . Apparently, this fixes it, but I'm not sure if this is a temporary solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).