# CORS Error When Rendering Firebase PhotoURL in Vue App

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, cors

This error is strange because it is not consistent. I am seeing this error on about 75% of page loads.

For context, I am building a Vue app that uses Firebase for user auth. When users login with Google SSO, I am trying to display the Users profile photo using the provided photoURL that is returned. The code looks like this:

```
<v-img 
    v-if="authStore.user?.photoURL" 
    :src="authStore.user.photoURL"
></v-img>
<v-icon 
    v-else 
    icon="mdi-account"
></v-icon>
```

However about 70% of the time, the image fails to load due to some CORS policy (which I'm assuming is on the google server side). Is there anything I can do to resolve this intermittent issue?

Attached is an image of the error I see:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that google rate limits calls to their services, because my referrer is localhost:port, the rate limit applies to all users accessing the API via localhost on the same port. Adding the referrerpolicy tag seems to help in development:

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570117/http403-forbidden-error-when-trying-to-load-img-src-with-google-profile-pic) for more info.