# Fetch Google profile image url by UID

Tags: ios, swift, google-people-api, gidsignin

I want to fetch the google profile image when UID is given to me .
I have [this](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) reference but m getting how to hit this url .
Please anyone provide me some example.

**EDIT:**
Here is my code

```
var googleImageUrl: URL?{
    let urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/\(uid)?fields=image&key=AIzaSyBfjHpl8DjU0IGw9mXbvK6HoNpY"
    return URL(string: urlString)
}

Alamofire.request(url)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any]


        } else {
            let apiError = ApiError(response: response)

        }
    })
```

when hitting this api, am always getting the error. Why i am not getting the response ?

Comment: you can directly hit the url via `NSUrlSession` or you can use `Alamofire` if you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128700/getting-google-profile-picture-url-with-user-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

Using Googles API, requires API key:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{UID}?fields=image&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Using Googles Picasaweb which does not require any API key:

```
http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/{UID}?alt=json
```

Code to get the image:

```
// Check what you want to return in the onCompletion and use it
func getImage(uid: String, onCompletion: @escaping (String) -> Void, onError: @escaping (NSError) -> Void) {
    let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/\(uid)?fields=image&key=AIzaSyBfjHpl8DjU0IGw9mXbvK6HoNpY"

    let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let object = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                print(object)
                // use the onCompletion in here
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: should i hit this url using alamofire or there is anything in google framework ?

Comment: I would recommend Alamofire, it´s a good tool for HTTP Networking and it´s well documented @PreetiRani

Answer (score 0):

The reference you listed points to the Google People API, which is different than the Google+ People API. If you want to use the Google People API you should use `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/{UID}?personFields=photo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

There are official examples at: https://developers.google.com/people/v1/read-people#get-the-person-for-a-google-account