# Get user name, avatar from google account

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-account

I'm developing an module that use GoogleAccountCredential to login, upload & download a file to GoogleDrive.

I want to get user first, last name and avatar of google account for display on my login feature.

I've try

```
 GoogleAccountCredential.getAccountName()
```

But It return only account name.

And see about [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) but not sure It can provide which I needed.

Don't know where to get those infomation, any suggestion also help me. It's awsome if have some examples

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ianhanniballake's answer works, but there is a better way to do it.
You don't need Google+ sign in to get user info.

Authorize with scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`

Make GET request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json`

You will get

```
{
 "id": "xx",
 "name": "xx",
 "given_name": "xx",
 "family_name": "xx",
 "link": "xx",
 "picture": "xx",
 "gender": "xx",
 "locale": "xx"
}
```

There are also language specific working codes in the following documentation: [Retrieving and Using OAuth 2.0 Credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/training/drive-apps/auth/credentials).

Have fun!

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I don't want login using google sign in, just use google email ID (like abc@gmail.com) or google account added on the phone. Can I do that?  
I've tried your link but It return Invalid request. I tried with this call: "String res = MyClass.getUserInfo(MyClass.getCredentials(MyClass.getAuthorizationUrl("dolphin.testers@gmail.com", null), null)).getFamilyName();"

Comment: Just get first, last name. I don't want avatar anymore

Comment: User must be logged in and authorize you to access his/her user profile. Otherwise,  it will be a serious privacy issue.

Answer (score 4):

To get this information, you must use [Google+ Sign In](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in), which gives you a [PlusClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html) object on successful login. You can then use [PlusClient.getCurrentPerson](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html#getCurrentPerson%28%29) to retrieve a [Person](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html) (who has a [getName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html#getName%28%29) and [getImage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html#getImage%28%29) method) and [PlusClient.getAccountName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html#getAccountName%28%29) to get the `accountName`, which you would use in the same way as if you had used `GoogleAccountCredential`:

```
String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, accountName, OAUTH2_SCOPE);
final GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
credential.setAccessToken(accessToken);
Drive driveConnection = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), 
    new GsonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName(APP_NAME).build();
```

Comment: yes you MUST login,that's the only way to get the `PlusClient` object which you can then go on to use to get whatever information are available to your app.(with permission of course)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Google has deprecated the userinfo endpoint that JunYoung mentioned in favor of the Google+ Sign-in. They will stop supporting the userinfo endpoint by August, 2014. See the link below for details:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration