# How to get user displayName and avatar of google account?

Tags: android, google-api, google-account

I have GoogleAccountCredential object and can get user email. But, I need to get his displayName and url of icon of avatar. Get you help me to do this?

The GoogleAccountCredential object I`m getting by this code:

```
 credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR));
```

it needed me for get google calendars.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName().replace(" ", "%20");
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                // String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                // int gender = currentPerson.getGender();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                // Log.i("personName", ""+personName);



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How I can to get GoogleApiClient object?

Comment: GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                    .setAccountName(userEmail)
                    .build();
            googleApiClient.connect();

Comment: Hi please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905066/get-user-name-avatar-from-google-account?rq=1